# What counts as a successful melee attack for Juan Marcano's Swordmage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, swordmage

I'm using [Juan Marcano's Swordmage](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/170971/Swordmage-Class?filters=45469) in D&D 5e (published via the Dungeon Masters Guild).

Most of the Swordmage's spells require a "successful melee attack" in order to be cast. Does this count as taking the Attack action for the sake of Extra Attack, or is that limited to specifically pure melee attacks?

I assume if it does, I am able to make a second melee attack only. Is that right?

Specifically, for spells such as Green Flame Blade and Frostwind Blade, which specify "a melee attack against an enemy within range" as part of the action to cast the spell, is this counted as an attack, a spell cast, or both for the purposes of Extra Attack?

Answer (score 10):

I'm the creator of the Swordmage referenced here.

The melee attack made as part of casting a spell does not count as taking the Attack action for the purposes of extra attacks. It's all part of casting the spell.

Let me know if you have any other questions, and thanks for your support!